# What is the intuition behind Adapted Process

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am reading up on stochastic process and in particular adapted process. I know that if $X_t$ is $F_t$ measurable for each t, then it is an adapted process.

But I do not understand the intuition behind the Adapted Process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *(2017.04.14) Wow, a downvote...*

The sigma-algebra $\mathfrak F_t$ represents what is known at time $t$. One asks that $X_t$ depends only on this.

For example, any i.i.d. and non degenerate process $(X_t)$ indexed by the nonnegative integers is adapted to the filtration $(\mathfrak F_t)$ defined by $\mathfrak F_t=\sigma(X_s;s\leqslant t)$ for every $t$ but $(X_t)$ is not adapted to the filtration $(\mathfrak H_t)$ defined by $\mathfrak H_t=\sigma(X_s;s\leqslant t-1)$.

Another example: let $(U_t)$ denote an i.i.d. process indexed by the nonnegative integers and consider, for every $t$, $\mathfrak F_t=\sigma(U_s;s\leqslant t)$. Then a process $(X_t)$ is adapted to the filtration $(\mathfrak F_t)$ if and only if, for every $t$, there exists some measurable function $g_t$ such that $X_t=g_t(U_0,U_1,\ldots,U_t)$.

Comment: One asks that Xt depends only on this => what do u mean by this?

Comment: That Xt is Ft-measurable.